# Regex to match words inside two or three curly braces

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I am writing a regular expression inside Kotlin app to match the following scenario: User will send string like this:

```
 1. "{{example}}" -> match: example 
 2. "{{{example2}}}" -> match: example2
 3. "{{example3}}}" -> do not match 
 4. "{example4}" -> do not match
 5. "{{{example5}}" -> do not match 
 6. "{{{{example6}}}}" -> do not match 
 7. "{{ example7 }}  some other words {{{example8}}}" -> match: example7 and example8 
 8. "{{{example9}}} some other words {{example10}} {{example11}}" -> match: example9, example10 and example 11
```

So to match only words between two or exactly three curly braces. This is the closest I got to my result:

```
regex = \{{2}([^{^}]+)\}{2}([^}])|\{{3}([^{^}]+)\}{3}([^}])
```

This matches everything fine except example5, you can also take a look here https://regex101.com/r/M0kw3j/1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That worked, except you need to replace `.*?` with `[^\{\}]*` to weed out `{{exam}ple}}` — i.e. `(?<!\{)(?:\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}|\{\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\}\})(?!\})`. There was nothing wrong with example 4 that I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something that might work for you:

```
(?<!\{)\{\{(?:([^{}]+)|\{([^{}]+)})}}(?!})
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/txhVth/1)

- Words that are between exactly 2 curly brackets will be in group 1.
- Words that are between exactly 3 curly brackets will be in group 2.

---

- `(?<!\{)` - Negative lookbehind for opening curly bracket.
- `\{\{` - Two literal curly (opening) brackets.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

  - `([^{}]+)` - A 1st capture group holding 1+ non-opening/closing brackets.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `\{([^{}]+)}` - A 2nd capture group with leading and trailing brackets.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `}}` - Two literal curly (closing) brackets.
- `(?!})` - Negative lookahead for closing curly bracket.

Comment: I know the demo requires the regex as is, but you may want to note that if it's be used in Java, all the \ would have to be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

Using alternation and [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)s, you may use this regex:

```sh
(?<!\{)(\{{3}[^{}\n]*}{3}|\{{2}[^{}\n]*}{2})(?!})
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SY1ZD9/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\{)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have `{` at the previous position
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `\{{3}`: Match 3 opening `{{{`
  - `[^{}\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `{` and `}`
  - `}{3}`: Match 3 closing `}}}`
  - `|`: OR ([alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html))
  - `\{{2}`: Match 2 opening `{{`
  - `[^{}\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `{` and `}`
  - `}{2}`: Match 2 closing `}}`
- `)`: Close capture group #1
- `(?!})`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `}` at the next position